# How to Check the Developer Office tools for Visual Studio 2015 is installed in the machine, using launch condition

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-2015

I have an Installer for our product which requires "Developer office tools for Visual Studio 2015" to be installed in the machine.

How can I add Launch condition to the installer to check whether "Developer office tools for Visual Studio 2015" is installed or not in the machine.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Regards,
Devaraj

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is customary to summarize your efforts so that answers will be helpful to people with similar problems. What have you tried, which step isn't working?

Comment: I have to support our product for VS2015 Community Edition So that Our VS addin will work with VS2015 CE. Our addin will throw error if "Developer office tools for VS2015 " is not installed. Thats why if we need to make it compatible with VS2015CE we have to check "Developer office tools for VS2015 " is already installed. I tried finding component ID of "Developer office tools for VS2015 " but could not find it. Tried with few GUID thinking that those might help but they didn't.

Comment: I hv to support our product for VS2015 Community Edition,So Our VS addin ll work with VS2015 CE.Our addin ll throw error if "Developer office tools for VS2015"(DOT4VS15) is not installed.we have to check DOT4VS15 is already installed/not.I tried finding component Id for DOT4VS15 but couldn't find it.Tried with few GUIDs from registry thinking that those might b component Ids but they didn't."Office 2010 VSTO Runtime" can b checked using RegKey:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R, but for DOT4VS15 its not same.so need help on how can I check this is installed/not in cur PC.